# How does Fairest blessing in Chronicles of Darkness 2e work?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, changeling-the-lost-2e

I'm not a native English speaker, and neither is my group. So we need a clarification.

The way it's phrased in the book (page 29) is like this:

> Blessing: Gain an additional dot of one Power Attribute at character creation. You may spend Willpower points on another character’s behalf for purposes of the usual three-die bonus or +2 Resistance trait increase. You may still only spend one Willpower point per action. This ability costs a point of Glamour if any Condition is in play that would cause contention or mistrust between the characters, such as Leveraged or Notoriety.

> Curse: In addition to your character’s other breaking points, she risks Clarity damage with a dice pool equal to half her Wyrd (rounded up) whenever her action — or inaction — leads directly to misfortune for her allies.

Part of our group believes this means the Fairest can spend willpower of other characters for her own rolls, which probably means an NPC. Counterpoint to this is that it seems broken, as the Fairest would be able to drain Willpower of Fey for nothing but Glamour.

The other part of the group believes that the Fairest gives others 3-dice bonus from her own Willpower pool. The arguments against this are as follows: "Help" action exists & the wording of curse implies that role of the Fairest is active rather than a buffer.

So, which is correct? Do the Fairest use their own Willpower pool to buff others, or do they use Willpower of other characters to improve their own rolls?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> So, which is correct? Do the Fairest use their own Willpower pool to
> buff others?

This one. The language "on another character’s behalf" means "for their benefit." You spend, they get the extra dice or Resistance.